# copy string from activity to another Android

Tags: android, variables, android-activity, global

at begining i want to say sorry for my bad english i hope u understand me.
I want to copy one string to another activity so i create :

```
package com.example.kliker;

import android.app.Application;


public class GlobalClass extends Application{

    private String name;
    private String email;


    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String aName) {

       name = aName;

    }

    public String getEmail() {

        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String aEmail) {

      email = aEmail;
    }

}
```

and in activity to set i use:

```
final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
globalVariable.setEmail("1");
globalVariable.setName("1");
```

and when i want get:

```
final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
a = globalVariable.getEmail();
b = globalVariable.getName();
mTextView.setText(a);
```

But it doesn't work ? I should refresh activity or something like that ?

http://speedy.sh/dvt94/Desktop.rar
Manifest,activity from i get and set, activity set, activity get

I would like to make one activity outstay data about category and food also i want to make another activity when we are in it and when we click on food it send informations about itself category and chosen food, main activity download that information and by means of them it build graphic sentence

Comment: can you show your activity?

Comment: http://speedy.sh/dvt94/Desktop.rar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bundle API - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html.

In your A Activity -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("value", "String Value");
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

And, in B Activity -

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
String value = extras.getString("value");
```

You would be interested in this http://hmkcode.com/android-passing-data-to-another-activities/

Comment: Yes i heard about it but what if i have a lot of activity ? I dont know...
If i doesnt have another option i use it

Comment: for such requirement we use 
Shared Preferences
Class with static getter/setter and variables 

(these are suggested by @user1676075 also)

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating your GlobalClass class twice so you are getting different variables. Try something like this in the same activity and see if it works.

```
final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
globalVariable.setEmail("1");
globalVariable.setName("1");

a = globalVariable.getEmail();
b = globalVariable.getName();
mTextView.setText(a);
```

Comment: I dont want get and set in same activity

Answer (score 0):

I can think of at least three decent choices:

1) Use a singleton (pros - simple; cons - won't persist across application lifetime).

2) Use SharedPreferences (easy enough to research); if you're really using it for something like username for the application (which is what it appears from the example) then SharedPreferences are appropriate.

3) Use an Intent to trigger the next activity from your current one, and pass the string as an extra (intent.putExtra(...), intent.getStringExtra(...)).